# How to keep an element active in css in a navigation system with a scrollspy?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Edit : I edited my original post because it was too long and I simlified the code with only what was necessary to understand the issue.**

Hello,

I'm currently coding a timeline design for my website. For that, I'm using an external scrollspy script: https://github.com/cferdinandi/gumshoe

I want to keep the circles active while going done so I used some css selector to do this

```
#my-awesome-nav :first-child ~ li:not(.active, .active ~ li) .color-change {
  background-color: rgb(255, 251, 0);
}
```

However with this selector all the circles are active before reaching the first circle and then the first circle won't keep the active state, please see the example below (in Fullscreen):

```js
var spy = new Gumshoe('#my-awesome-nav a');
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.stem-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}

#my-awesome-nav {
  position: fixed;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#my-awesome-nav li {
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

#my-awesome-nav li a {
  border: solid 3px black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1F2933;
}

#my-awesome-nav li a .color-change {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: #1F2933;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#my-awesome-nav li.active a .color-change {
  background-color: rgb(255, 251, 0);
}

#my-awesome-nav :first-child ~ li:not(.active, .active ~ li) .color-change {
  background-color: rgb(255, 251, 0);
}

.nav-item {
  padding-top: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.nav-item > div {
  height: 500px;
  width: 800px;
}

#step-one {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#step-two {
  background-color: red;
}

#step-three {
  background-color: green;
}

#step-four {
  background-color: blue;
}

#step-five {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/cferdinandi/gumshoe@4/dist/gumshoe.polyfills.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="stem-nav">
    <ul id="my-awesome-nav">
      <li><a href="#step-one">
          <div class="color-change"></div>
        </a></li>
      <li><a href="#step-two">
          <div class="color-change"></div>
        </a></li>
      <li><a href="#step-three">
          <div class="color-change"></div>
        </a></li>
      <li><a href="#step-four">
          <div class="color-change"></div>
        </a></li>
      <li><a href="#step-five">
          <div class="color-change"></div>
        </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-item">
    <div id="step-one"></div>
    <div id="step-two"></div>
    <div id="step-three"></div>
    <div id="step-four"></div>
    <div id="step-five"></div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue, I switched from css to javascript in order to solve it, I couldn't find a way to solve it with css. I removed this line:

```
#my-awesome-nav :first-child ~ li:not(.active, .active ~ li) .color-change {
  background-color: rgb(255, 251, 0);
}
```

Then I added this javascript:

```
var spy = new Gumshoe('#my-awesome-nav a');
let navUl = document.getElementById("my-awesome-nav");
document.addEventListener('gumshoeActivate', function (event) {
    var li = event.target;

  let children = navUl.children;
  for(let i = 0; i < li.dataset.index; i++) {
    children[i].className = "active";
  }
}, false);
```

Final result:

```js
var spy = new Gumshoe('#my-awesome-nav a');
let navUl = document.getElementById("my-awesome-nav");
document.addEventListener('gumshoeActivate', function (event) {
    var li = event.target;

  let children = navUl.children;
  for(let i = 0; i < li.dataset.index; i++) {
    children[i].className = "active";
  }
}, false);
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.stem-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}

#my-awesome-nav {
  position: fixed;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#my-awesome-nav li {
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

#my-awesome-nav li a {
  border: solid 3px black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1F2933;
}

#my-awesome-nav li a .color-change {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: #1F2933;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#my-awesome-nav li.active a .color-change {
  background-color: rgb(255, 251, 0);
}

.nav-item {
  padding-top: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.nav-item > div {
  height: 500px;
  width: 800px;
  padding-bottom: 500px;
}

#step-one {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#step-two {
  background-color: red;
}

#step-three {
  background-color: green;
}

#step-four {
  background-color: blue;
}

#step-five {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/cferdinandi/gumshoe@4/dist/gumshoe.polyfills.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="stem-nav">
    <ul id="my-awesome-nav">
      <li data-index="0"><a href="#step-one">
          <div class="color-change"></div>
        </a></li>
      <li data-index="1"><a href="#step-two">
          <div class="color-change"></div>
        </a></li>
      <li data-index="2"><a href="#step-three">
          <div class="color-change"></div>
        </a></li>
      <li data-index="3"><a href="#step-four">
          <div class="color-change"></div>
        </a></li>
      <li data-index="4"><a href="#step-five">
          <div class="color-change"></div>
        </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-item">
    <div id="step-one"></div>
    <div id="step-two"></div>
    <div id="step-three"></div>
    <div id="step-four"></div>
    <div id="step-five"></div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```